# Is Java 8 filters on Stream of large list more time consuming than for loop?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I was replacing one of my legacy code from simple for loop over a list to Java 8 stream and filters.

I have the for loop like below:

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
for(int i: numbers) {
    if((i > 4) && (i % 2 == 0)) {
         System.out.println("First even number in list more than 4 : " +  numbers.get(i))
         break;
    }
}
```

Here I have 6 iterations of the loop. When 6 is obtained, I print it.

Now, I am replacing it with below:

```
numbers.stream()
       .filter(e -> e > 4)
       .filter(e -> e % 2 == 0)
       .findFirst()
```

I am confused, if we are applying filter twice on the list, then is the time complexity more than the for loop case or is there something I am missing?

Comment: The stream is lazy and is not collected until a terminal operation (`findFirst` in this case). It will therefore only traverse the list once.

Comment: Just a question.  Why not filter once with e > 4 && e %2 ==0 ?

Comment: @marstran what does 'It will therefore traverse the list once mean'? How will it do it then?

Comment: Why are you calling `numbers.get(i)` in your original loop? `i` will already be the **values** in the list, it's **not an index**. So you're using the **values** in the list to actually index into the list. This **may** be what you intend, but it's unusual and your stream implementation does nothing like that.

Comment: @RandomCoder_01 A better question is, why?  The obvious answers are not very good.  It may be fewer lines of code, but it's not necessarily more readable or maintainable.  And while I suspect you think it is faster, that's not actually true; the two wlll be fused together in the same pass.  We should strive to write code that is as clear as possible; crufting it up for perceived concision or performance benefits is almost always premature.

Comment: Since nobody has mentioned it yet: in the loop version, there's also the unboxing of the `Integer` to `int` which has a performance impact (only `n` times though). You can get around that by using an `IntStream`. That's only for this particular case and not the general "loop vs stream" question though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is **no**. A stream with multiple `filter`, `map`, or other intermediate operations is not necessarily slower than an equivalent for loop.

The reason for this is that all intermediate Stream operations are *lazy*, meaning that they are not actually applied individually at the time the `filter` method is called, but are instead all evaluated at once during the *terminal operation* (`findFirst()` in this case). From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps):

> Stream operations are divided into intermediate and terminal operations, and are combined to form stream pipelines. A stream pipeline consists of a source (such as a Collection, an array, a generator function, or an I/O channel); followed by zero or more intermediate operations such as Stream.filter or Stream.map; and a terminal operation such as Stream.forEach or Stream.reduce.
>
> Intermediate operations return a new stream. They are always lazy; executing an intermediate operation such as filter() does not actually perform any filtering, but instead creates a new stream that, when traversed, contains the elements of the initial stream that match the given predicate. Traversal of the pipeline source does not begin until the terminal operation of the pipeline is executed.

In practice, since your two pieces of code do not compile to exactly the same bytecode, there will likely be some minor performance difference between them, but logically they do very similar things and will perform very similarly.

Comment: And in some cases, the stream can be _faster_ than the corresponding for loop, because the per-element-access costs for many collections are lower with `Spliterator` (which powers streams) than with `Iterator` (which powers for-loops).  Write clear code; the performance will follow.